# nginx reverse proxy with tomcat not working

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, proxy, spring-saml

I am trying to proxy tomcat using nginx. I have this configuration below. Now the problem I am facing is if I access the url by IP(192.168.2.6) then it gets redirected to /auth_app is tomcat which is perfectly fine. The tomcat url redirect to a third party SAML2 provider and once it authenticated it redirected to http://localhost:8080/auth_app/ instead of http://192.168.2.6/auth_app/ and because of that my application doesn't open as tomcat is running on 192.168.2.6 and not localhost.

```
server { 
    listen 80 default_server; 
    server_name _; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/abc_error.log; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/abc_access.log; 
    rewrite ^/?$ /auth_app; 
    location /auth_app { 
        proxy_redirect off; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/auth_app/; 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There should be a config setting in your tomcat app to set the redirect URL to `http://192.168.2.6/auth_app/`.